# Kill Android Activity having a main Thread

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I having problem with my activities flow. The flow is as follow:

```
 Splash -> MainMenu -> Launching -> Starting -> Instructions -> MagicPower
```

so as at MagicPower activity I want to come back to MainMenu after some sleep() time!
     The problem is that MainMenu activity did not finish at all and shows itself twice the times. How can I overcome this problem! As I have been trying at my end as:

```
  package com.app.imagic;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.graphics.Typeface;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MagicPower extends Activity {

///////////
private TextView lookme;
private volatile boolean running=true;
private int i;
private TextView gone;

///////////
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_magic_power);
    lookme=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.LOOK);
    lookme.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    gone=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.GONE);
    gone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/crazy.TTF");
    gone.setTypeface(face);
    lookme.setTypeface(face);


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    runThread();
}
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  private void runThread() {
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            while ( i++ < 4) {

                if(i==3){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    startActivity(new Intent(MagicPower.this,MainMenu.class));

                    running=false;
                    finish();
                    break;
                    }
                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(i==1){
                                lookme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }

                            if(i==2){
                                gone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                }


                        }
                        });
                    Thread.sleep(2500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return;
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
    }
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.magic_power, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
}
```

}

It should be like after MainMenu; the MainMenu Activity should not again come to screen! Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: I've several suggestions: 1. Call `finish();` 4 times in the different contexts to get you back to the `MainMenu`. 2. Call this `KeyEvent k = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK);
Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(k);` - it's corresponding to the back key pressed, but that's essentially the same a calling `finish();`.

Comment: An alternative to all this is to use the flag from here -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code here:

```
if(i==3){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    startActivity(intent);
    startActivity(new Intent(MagicPower.this,MainMenu.class));

    running=false;
    finish();
    break;
}
```

You are yourself starting `MainMenu` activity twice. Once here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenu.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

startActivity(intent);
```

And then again:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MagicPower.this,MainMenu.class));
```

I would suggest you remove this line:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MagicPower.this,MainMenu.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change [**android:launchMode**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of MainMenu activity in your AndroidManifet.xml. Probably, "**singleTop**" is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

You can use this:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

It will preserve the state of the `Activity`.